# Assigning column based on Quantile() vs qcut

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 'Zip', 'Median Income' and I'd like to add another column based on what quantile the income is.

Running `dfq = dfq.quantile([.1, .25, .50, .75, .9])` it returns the following which I believe is correct for the 'Median Income'.

```
               Zip  Median Income
0.10  60303.80       32176.90
0.25  60608.25       39896.00
0.50  60627.00       49755.00
0.75  60645.75       59829.25
0.90  60664.70       75555.30
```

`print(dfq['Median Income'].median())`
49755.0

So the .50 and median line up correctly.

What I'd like to do is assign a column next to Median Income with the quantile it falls into, but can't seem to do that easily?

I tried the qcut function.

```
dfq['quantile'] = pd.qcut(dfq['Median Income'], 5, labels=['10%','25%','50%','75%','90%'])
```

But the results seem different from using the quantile function since it separates the rows equally (around 70 rows)

Am I missing something here, isn't the quantile calculation correct vs my qcut?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about qcut, but another option would be the create a new column based on those quartiles you found as the condition value, maybe a function to do that if you need to do it multiple times. For [reference](https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/).

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that also using a for loop and nested if statements etc. I would just like to avoid that and was not sure why I couldn't assign the .quantiles() to a variable etc.